# Doubling the size of array based on passed in integer value

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I am practicing arrays and I am unsure what is question even asking.
Complete the method called `addInt`
This is just a practice code.
This method should add the passed in integer to the array. If the array is full you should double the size of the array and then add the integer to the array.

```
public class SimpleArrays {
private int[] numbers;
public SimpleArrays(int... nums) {
    numbers = new int[nums.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = nums[i];
    }
}
public void addInt(int i) {
}
public int sum() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i : numbers) {
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
public void doubleSize() {
    int[] doubleArray = new int[numbers.length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        doubleArray[i] = numbers[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: addInt , the question is asking you to add the integer into the array, not add the numbers .

Comment: Just call `doubleSize` then insert behind last item.

Comment: "I am unsure what is question even asking" It would be helpful you you clarify for yourself what you are asking before posting. Otherwise, end your `public void doubleSize()` by a statement of `this.numbers = doubleArray;` and then come back and tell us why that one is needed.

Comment: Sorry for not stating properly. I do not need to change anything in the other methods as they are working against test case. However I need to add something to addInt method. I gave what that method needs to do

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking you to add int i to your numbers array.

Let's say the numbers array has 1, 5, 7, 9 in it. It looks like this:

`{1, 5, 7, 9}`

If you call addInt like this `addInt(11);` then you want the numbers array to look like this:

`{1, 5, 7, 9, 11}`

But if the array can't hold the number you want to add, then you need to make it bigger so it can hold the new number. So before you add the number 11, you make sure there is room in the array first. If there isn't, then you double the array.

Comment: exactly, I am not sure how to assume general case here

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your doubleSize() function you should add a statement to make sure your `numbers` variable refers to the memory allocated to the `doubleArray` array.

The following statement should do it

```
numbers = doubleArray;
```

Your doubleSize() should then look like this

```
public void doubleSize() {
    int[] doubleArray = new int[numbers.length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        doubleArray[i] = numbers[i];
    }
    numbers = doubleArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I figured out. As always appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code there is no use of doubleArray that you created locally.
You should return it form the douleSize() method or re-initialize it to numbers array.

then your code would be some meaningful otherwise it a illogical question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing your code with something more succinct.

This for the sum:

```
return IntStream.of(numbers).sum();
```

and this for doubling:

```
numbers = Arrays.copyOf(numbers, numbers.length * 2);
System.arrayCopy(numbers, 0, numbers, numbers.length / 2, numbers.length / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine.

```
public void addInt(int i){
   int size = numbers.length;
   if(numbers[size - 1]!= 0){
       //replace doubleSize(); with the following
        numbers = Arrays.copyOf(numbers, 2 * size );

       numbers[size] = i;
   }else{
       for(int j = 0; j<size; j++) {
          if(numbers[j] == 0){
              numbers[j] = i;
              break;
          }
   }
}
```

Or for better results, you can change array declaration to

```
private Integer[] numbers;
```

and initialisation to

```
numbers = new Integer[nums.length];
```

So the above code can be modified to

```
public void addInt(int i){
   int size = numbers.length;
   if(numbers[size - 1]!= null){
       //replace doubleSize(); with the following
        numbers = Arrays.copyOf(numbers, 2 * size );
       numbers[size] = i;
   }else{
       for(int j = 0; j<size; j++) {
          if(numbers[j] == null){
              numbers[j] = i;
              break;
          }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps``